# Parsing XML in node.js results in extreme memory usage

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing

I've written a small node.js application which traverses a 1.8GB xml file and does some database action on the different elements. But I'm running into memory problems.

```
var fs        = require('fs')
  , path      = require('path')
  , XmlStream = require('xml-stream')
  , pg = require('pg')
  , conString = "postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/db"
  , schema = 'public'
  ;

function storeInDB(data){
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }

    var sql = 'INSERT INTO '+schema+'.table (field1, field2) VALUES ($1, $2) ';

    client.query(sql,data, function(err, result) {
      done();
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
    });
   })
 }

 var stream = fs.createReadStream('../path/to/some_large.xml');
 var xml = new XmlStream(stream);

 // Find the certificate entry and do things with it.
 xml.on('endElement: certificate', function(item) {
    var data = [item.field1, item.field2, ......];

    storeInDB(data);
 });
```

Although this works it starts to consume gradually more RAM. In htop I see the percentage of memory climb on a steady pace; up until my complete RAM is used and the SWAP file kicks in. This results in a considerable lag because of the IO. This is around the 400.000 processed certificates; the file contains roughly 2.5 mil certificates.

Something is eating memory, but I don't know what. XML-stream should not load the data in memory as the built up of the memory proves. But it looks like the data processed is not flushed from memory somehow.

Is there a way to flush memory every x certificates? Or is the application 'wrong'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you bound:

```
xml.on('endElement: certificate')
```

will fire extremely quickly over and over without waiting for writes to the DB to complete. Update storeInDB to call this:

```
xml.pause() // Put this as the first line in storeInDB to prevent too many events
```

and put this in the query callback:

```
xml.resume(); // Resume parsing 
done();
```

You could improve this to only call the pause and resume events if more than 5 queries are in progress etc. but you get the idea.

It may also be worth looking into not using the connection pool of pg module and instead use a single connection via client.connect.

Comment: So if I'm understanding it correct the db connection is causing the increasing memory usage? Because it gets fired to quick for the pool to handle the requests? So if I use the `pause()/resume()` every x queries where x will be the max connection pool - 1 I would be save?

Comment: It may not be the only cause, but it's definitely an issue I think as it's happening so fast and frequently on a huge dataset.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll unleash the new code on the 2.5milion certificates :) Keep you posted!

Comment: Awesome, as I said, you can probably speed it up by allowing a certain number of concurrent calls to storeInDB but that's just nice to have :D

Comment: It 'only' took an small hour to parse the whole file. And luckily i'm not parsing it every day :)